# Unable to create new app in LinkedIn always internal error

Tags: linkedin-api

Been trying to create an app in 
https://www.linkedin.com/secure/developer?newapp

this is for a customer to use wordpress plugin to post to their company page
For some reason I'm every time I try I'm getting 'Internal error, try again later'

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue going on.

when I shortened the fields (my problem was a long value for company name), it worked.
try to put short values in the fields.

hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

When I got this error it was because I was trying to use a SVG vs a PNG as a logo. The error provided is not very helpful.